# Facebook likes reset when switching to https. Never been able to get back original like count

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

It's quite strange and a bit frustrating as I've never been able to resolve this and it has been a few months but I haven't found anything or any explanation why. Basically here is what happened:
I had an old website design that was on http. I was redesigning it when I decided to switch to https. At the time I had around 13K+ likes. After enabling https to the website and forcing http to redirect to it, the like count reset to about 100-odd likes. Even after disabling the forced https, the likes never returned. Could anyone offer an sugestions or am I sod out of luck?

Here's the code from the old website:

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(a, b, c) {
    var d = a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];
    a.getElementById(c) || (a = a.createElement(b), a.id = c, a.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", d.parentNode.insertBefore(a, d)) })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.WEBSITE.com/"
data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50"
data-show-faces="false">
</div>
```

And currently on the website:

```
<!--- Top of body -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=668081449932569&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!---somewhere on the site --->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.waterfoxproject.org" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not at all. Have had to suck it up for the past year and try rebuild the likes we lost unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same problem with one of our website that was switched to https and solved the problem by changing the data-href to point to the https site instead of http. We immediately went back to our previous number of likes.

On the [facebook like button page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) you can enter your URL (with and without https) to see how many likes are attributed to that URL.

I tried your URL on that page and unfortunately it seems that in your case the number of like for http and https are the same.

I'm afraid this doesn't resolve your problem, but maybe someone else who has the same problem might benefit from this answer.

Comment: I get the same zero(actually new 84) Likes using old and new URL. It seems Facebook Crawl detected 301 redirect on HTTP version Url and reset Likes to 0 and I do not find a way to bring them back. It could be that if I remove 301 redirect from HTTP version url I will get Likes back eventually. I choose go with HTTPS and leave Likes.