# My facebook like button did reset (march 2016)

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like, reset

I'm having an issue with my Facebook like button. I have it on my website since a few years and it has always worked fine. But around one week ago, the counter did reset. It had a prior count of 68 and went to 1. I did not change the integration code or anything. Here it is :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('http://www.final-fantasy.ch'); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=110&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:25px"></iframe>
```

In january this year, I did activate SSL on my site. The HTTP address is now doing a redirect to HTTPS. Up to last week, the FB like count did still appear correctly (I cannot be sure it did increase, but I think so... hard to remember exactly). Could this change be the source of the problem ?

Or have anyone any other clue about what is happening ?

Does anyone have any clue what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is because of the switch from http to https, as it´s a different URL now. You can try changing the og:url back to http to keep your likes - but it may not work if you redirect from http to https. Better: just forget about the old likes. It´s just a number anyway.

More information: [Facebook likes reset when switching to https. Never been able to get back original like count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184381/facebook-likes-reset-when-switching-to-https-never-been-able-to-get-back-origin)

Comment: If I had changed the integration code, I would agree with you. But the fact is : the button still refers to an HTTP link, not an HTTPS one.

Comment: didn´t you say the http address redirects to https? afaik facebook follows a redirect.

Comment: True, but in the HTML code to integrate the button, I still refer to the HTTP address. But I guess you are right, Facebook does follow the link when someone does click on the "like" button (obvious because there is a preview of the page in Facebook). The count did probably reset when the first user did click on "like" on the HTTPS version. At that time, Facebook followed the link and could not match the 68 previous likes to the first one on HTTPS... Well, nothing really bad as you say.